# adam mount point gives error

Tags: 2011, ecl

There are couple of CMS servers (load balanced). When trying to access the mount point of adam on one of the servers the following error is shown. Other servers working fine.

Error:

> Type 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedFault' in Assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable

Certificate renewal was done on all the CMS servers. This mount point worked initially before certificate renewal. After renewal also, it worked fine once. Suddenly we are getting the above issue.
Other CMS servers are working fine after certificate renewal. Problem is with only one server.

Event log shows this error message:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:10'. AND SAML: An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message. StackTrace Information Details: Server stack trace: at Tridion.Ecl.Adam.Api.AdamConnector.GetItems(Boolean& isLast, String searchExpression, String sortExpression, Int32 pageNumber, Int32 itemsPerPage, String classificationId, Boolean structureOnly)

Comment: My guess is that the serialization error is masking the real error (i.e. it cannot return the error because it's not serializable). Have you checked the event log on the machine where it fails?

Comment: Hi Peter, I see below in event log: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:10'. AND SAML: An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message.

StackTrace Information Details:

Server stack trace: 
   at Tridion.Ecl.Adam.Api.AdamConnector.GetItems(Boolean& isLast, String searchExpression, String sortExpression, Int32 pageNumber, Int32 itemsPerPage, String classificationId, Boolean structureOnly)

Answer (score 4):

Seems like certificate problem between ADAM and Hintech AdamConnector

Possible reasons:

- Wrong certificate
- User do not have permissions to access certificate
- Certificate not trusted